# What's the deal with BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT with more than 64 members?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, boost-fusion

Trying to create boilerplate code for a huge struct with more than 64 members and the `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` macro but it fails to compile in VS2015 Update 3. I've tried to play with `BOOST_FUSION_HAS_VARIADIC_VECTOR` and `BOOST_PP_LIMIT_TUPLE` but no luck, I keep getting the same error if I add more than 64 members to `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`. Did not find any mention of limits the  `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` has except when it is in C++03 mode. Am I missing something?

Live at [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/022bc0730c6fcadb)

Code:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp>

struct Data
{
    int a01 = 1;
    int a02 = 1;
    int a03 = 1;
    int a04 = 1;
    int a05 = 1;
    int a06 = 1;
    int a07 = 1;
    int a08 = 1;
    int a09 = 1;
    int a10 = 1;
    int a11 = 1;
    int a12 = 1;
    int a13 = 1;
    int a14 = 1;
    int a15 = 1;
    int a16 = 1;
    int a17 = 1;
    int a18 = 1;
    int a19 = 1;
    int a20 = 1;
    int a21 = 1;
    int a22 = 1;
    int a23 = 1;
    int a24 = 1;
    int a25 = 1;
    int a26 = 1;
    int a27 = 1;
    int a28 = 1;
    int a29 = 1;
    int a30 = 1;
    int a31 = 1;
    int a32 = 1;
    int a33 = 1;
    int a34 = 1;
    int a35 = 1;
    int a36 = 1;
    int a37 = 1;
    int a38 = 1;
    int a39 = 1;
    int a40 = 1;
    int a41 = 1;
    int a42 = 1;
    int a43 = 1;
    int a44 = 1;
    int a45 = 1;
    int a46 = 1;
    int a47 = 1;
    int a48 = 1;
    int a49 = 1;
    int a50 = 1;
    int a51 = 1;
    int a52 = 1;
    int a53 = 1;
    int a54 = 1;
    int a55 = 1;
    int a56 = 1;
    int a57 = 1;
    int a58 = 1;
    int a59 = 1;
    int a60 = 1;
    int a61 = 1;
    int a62 = 1;
    int a63 = 1;
    int a64 = 1;
    int a65 = 1;
    int a66 = 1;
    int a67 = 1;
    int a68 = 1;
    int a69 = 1;
    int a70 = 1;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Data, a01, a02, a03, a04, a05, a06, a07, a08, a09, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17,
                          a18, a19, a20, a21, a22, a23, a24, a25, a26, a27, a28, a29, a30, a31, a32, a33, a34, a35, a36,
                          a37, a38, a39, a40, a41, a42, a43, a44, a45, a46, a47, a48, a49, a50, a51, a52, a53, a54, a55,
                          a56, a57, a58, a59, a60, a61, a62, a63/*, a64, a65, a66, a67, a68, a69, a70*/) // uncomment the a64 to get the error


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

MSVC errors:

> 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): warning C4003: not enough actual
>   parameters for macro 'BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM_III'
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM_0':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2146:
>   syntax error: missing '>' before identifier
>   'BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ_a64' 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a01': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a02': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a03': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a04':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a05': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a06': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a07': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a08': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a09':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a10': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a11': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a12': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a13': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a14':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a15': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a16': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a17': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a18': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a19':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a20': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a21': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a22': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a23': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a24':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a25': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a26': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a27': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a28': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a29':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a30': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a31': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a32': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a33': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a34':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a35': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a36': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a37': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a38': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a39':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a40': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a41': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a42': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a43': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a44':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a45': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a46': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a47': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a48': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a49':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a50': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a51': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a52': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a53': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a54':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a55': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a56': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a57': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a58': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a59':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a60': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a61': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a62': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a63': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a64':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a65': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a66': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a67': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a68': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a69':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a70': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(116): error
>   C2059: syntax error: ')' 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2977:
>   'boost::fusion::traits::tag_of': too many template arguments 1> 
>   packages\boost.1.61.0.0\lib\native\include\boost\fusion\support\tag_of.hpp(71):
>   note: see declaration of 'boost::fusion::traits::tag_of'
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2913: explicit specialization;
>   'boost::fusion::traits::tag_of' is not a specialization of a class
>   template 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2913: explicit
>   specialization; 'boost::fusion::traits::tag_of' is not a
>   specialization of a class template 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2440:
>   'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'int' 1> 
>   consoleapplication23.cpp(119): note: The initializer contains too many
>   elements 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(116): error C2059: syntax error:
>   '(' 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM_0': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2146: syntax error: missing
>   '>' before identifier 'BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ_a64'
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a01': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a02':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a03': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a04': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a05': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a06': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a07':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a08': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a09': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a10': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a11': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a12':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a13': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a14': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a15': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a16': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a17':
>   undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065:
>   'a18': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error
>   C2065: 'a19': undeclared identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119):
>   error C2065: 'a20': undeclared identifier
>   1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): error C2065: 'a21': undeclared
>   identifier 1>consoleapplication23.cpp(119): fatal error C1003: error
>   count exceeds 100; stopping compilation

GCC errors:

> main.cpp:80:1: error: macro "BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM_III" requires 2
>   arguments, but only 1 given
>                              a56, a57, a58, a59, a60, a61, a62, a63, a64, a65, a66, a67, a68, a69, a70) // uncomment the a64 to get the
>   error  ^                   In file included from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/preprocessor/seq/seq.hpp:16:0,
>                    from /usr/local/include/boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp:20,
>                    from main.cpp:1: main.cpp:77:1: error: 'BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM_III' was not declared in this scope 
>   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Data, a01, a02, a03, a04, a05, a06, a07,
>   a08, a09, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17,  ^ In file included
>   from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp:28:0,
>                    from main.cpp:1: main.cpp:77:1: error: template argument 1 is invalid  BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Data, a01, a02, a03,
>   a04, a05, a06, a07, a08, a09, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, 
>   ^ In file included from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/preprocessor/seq/seq.hpp:16:0,
>                    from /usr/local/include/boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp:20,
>                    from main.cpp:1: main.cpp:77:1: error: 'BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM_III' was not declared in this scope 
>   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Data, a01, a02, a03, a04, a05, a06, a07,
>   a08, a09, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17,  ^ In file included
>   from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp:28:0,
>                    from main.cpp:1: main.cpp:77:1: error: template argument 1 is invalid  BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Data, a01, a02, a03,
>   a04, a05, a06, a07, a08, a09, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, 
>   ^ In file included from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/preprocessor/control/if.hpp:18:0,
>                    from /usr/local/include/boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp:17,
>                    from main.cpp:1: main.cpp:77:1: error: 'BOOST_PP_IIF_0' does not name a type  BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Data,
>   a01, a02, a03, a04, a05, a06, a07, a08, a09, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14,
>   a15, a16, a17,  ^ In file included from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/preprocessor/seq/seq.hpp:16:0,
>                    from /usr/local/include/boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp:20,
>                    from main.cpp:1: main.cpp:77:1: error: 'BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM_III' was not declared in this scope 
>   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Data, a01, a02, a03, a04, a05, a06, a07,
>   a08, a09, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17,  ^ In file included
>   from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp:28:0,
>                    from main.cpp:1: main.cpp:77:1: error: template argument 1 is invalid  BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Data, a01, a02, a03,
>   a04, a05, a06, a07, a08, a09, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, 
>   ^ In file included from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/preprocessor/seq/seq.hpp:16:0,
>                    from /usr/local/include/boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp:20,
>                    from main.cpp:1: main.cpp:77:1: error: 'BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM_III' was not declared in this scope 
>   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Data, a01, a02, a03, a04, a05, a06, a07,
>   a08, a09, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17,  ^ In file included
>   from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp:28:0,
>                    from main.cpp:1: main.cpp:77:1: error: template argument 1 is invalid  BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Data, a01, a02, a03,
>   a04, a05, a06, a07, a08, a09, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, 
>   ^ In file included from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/preprocessor/seq/seq.hpp:16:0,
>                    from /usr/local/include/boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp:20,
>                    from main.cpp:1: main.cpp:77:1: error: 'BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM_III' was not declared in this scope 
>   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Data, a01, a02, a03, a04, a05, a06, a07,
>   a08, a09, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17,  ^ In file included
>   from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp:28:0,
>                    from main.cpp:1: main.cpp:77:1: error: template argument 1 is invalid  BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Data, a01, a02, a03,
>   a04, a05, a06, a07, a08, a09, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, 
>   ^
>
> g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

Comment: how about a [mcve]?

Comment: and what's the error?

Comment: @m.s. Great idea, definitely it will help

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc added to the question

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` has two parameters per class element, type and name. MSVC only supports [127 macro parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft39hh4x.aspx) while the Standard recommends 255. This explains why the 64'th element, requiring 128 macro parameters, fails to compile on MSVC++.

Comment: `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` only needs 1 parameter per class element, its name.  see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html

Comment: Since Coliru fails on the same 64th element I guess CGG has the same limitation, or, more likely, there is something in Boost Fusion that limits it

Comment: @m.s.: In which case it's using `Boost.TypeOf` to figure out the type. I'll bet that gets you macro parameters 64-128 during macro expansion.

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg maybe `BOOST_PP_LIMIT_VARIADIC` causes this? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/limit_variadic.html

Comment: The limitation seems to be in Boost.Preprocessor, especifically in the BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ macro. [Simple test](http://rextester.com/ZPLMB46692).

Comment: @jv_: It's possible the limitations are two sides of one coin: Boost may have set its limit so that it compiles on MSVC++.

Comment: @jv_, gotcha! # define BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ_64(e0, e1, ...(e63). looks like you are right. Any know workaround for it?

Comment: @MSalters, I didnt find any mention of any limit of variadics size in MSVC

Comment: Changing BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ and BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE seems to [make it work for 64 elements](http://rextester.com/JPO75225).

Comment: @jv: Looks like you got the right answer - want to turn your comment into a proper answer?

Comment: @jv_, I've already tried it, to no avail, looks like I'm missing something, will check it tomorrow. on the other hand I dont get it, what exactly stops all this macro stuff to handle correctly any number of parameters?

Comment: If one had to use this with too many parameters, how would one handroll what the macro is doing?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ()` is only implemented for 0 to 64 arguments (one of which is taken by the type in `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT()`).

Ref: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/boost/preprocessor/tuple/to_seq.hpp

As a workaround, you can put some of your struct members into their own struct, and use that struct type as a member in the outer struct.  This lets you call `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT()` twice: once for each inner struct type, and once for the outer.  This easily gives you 63*63 = 3969 maximum fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this limitation of `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ()` if you call the version without `BOOST_PP_VARIADICS` support

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Data,
(auto,a01)(auto,a02)(auto,a03)(auto,a04)(auto,a05)(auto,a06)(auto,a07)(auto,a08)(auto,a09)(auto,a10)
(auto,a11)(auto,a12)(auto,a13)(auto,a14)(auto,a15)(auto,a16)(auto,a17)(auto,a18)(auto,a19)(auto,a20)
(auto,a21)(auto,a22)(auto,a23)(auto,a24)(auto,a25)(auto,a26)(auto,a27)(auto,a28)(auto,a29)(auto,a30)
(auto,a31)(auto,a32)(auto,a33)(auto,a34)(auto,a35)(auto,a36)(auto,a37)(auto,a38)(auto,a39)(auto,a40)
(auto,a41)(auto,a42)(auto,a43)(auto,a44)(auto,a45)(auto,a46)(auto,a47)(auto,a48)(auto,a49)(auto,a50)
(auto,a51)(auto,a52)(auto,a53)(auto,a54)(auto,a55)(auto,a56)(auto,a57)(auto,a58)(auto,a59)(auto,a60)
(auto,a61)(auto,a62)(auto,a63)(auto,a64)(auto,a65)(auto,a66)(auto,a67)(auto,a68)(auto,a69)(auto,a70))
```

I could not test it with MSVC but it works with gcc.